# How to draw density plots for bivariate distributions in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a bivariate data with different correlations. I want to show the density plots in 3d for them. How to do that in R?

```
n = 2000; m1 = 0; m2 = 0; s1 =1; s2 = 1;
plotcor = function(r){
  x = rnorm(n,m1,s1)
  y = s2*r*(x-m1)/s1+m2 + s2*rnorm(n,0,sqrt(1-r^2))
  plot(x,y, main = paste('Correlation =', r))
  abline(lm(y~x), col = 'red')
}
par(mfrow=c(3,3),oma=c(0,0,2,0))
for (i in c(-1,-.75,-.5,-0.25,0,0.25,0.5,.75,1)){
  plotcor(i)
}
```

[image]
Similar to the above I wants to write a function which gives me density plot as like [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/33/)

Comment: It seems you want a bivariate [kernel density estimate plot](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ks/html/plot.kde.html).

Comment: And maybe package `QRM` for a [parametric bivariate density plot](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/QRM/html/Bidensplot.html). In this case you would plug in, say, function `dmvnorm` from package `mvtnorm`.